# Bulk remove default applications in Android (with Terminal Emulator)

Tags: android, galaxy

I am trying to remove default applications from my rooted Galaxy S2 phone.

I am using "Android Terminal Emulator" to remove the apps like so:

```
su

mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblk3 /system

ls /system/app

rm /system/app/<app-name>
```

Problem is that I made a list of apps I want to remove but it's over 60 apps. Is there a way to remove multiple apps at once? Or is there a way to run terminal emulator from windows pc so that I can quickly copy paste the command over and over again?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question. Please use http://android.stackexchange.com for end-user questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the device to a machine with ADB running. So that you can issue commands over the PC to your device via ADB.

Answer (score 0):

There is a magisk module named debloat. It can be accessed through terminal emulator on android to get rid of those apps. It also supports multi-removal of apps. It is very easy if you are comfortable with terminal.